# CMUSphinx recognises wrong words?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

Here is my grammer

#

## JSGF V1.0;

grammar tc;

<perspid> = myteamcenter | structure manager | schedule manager | classification | organization;

public <st> = sendto <perspid>;

#

I also do have the necessary dictionary generated.

My only problem is if I speak any words which are not present in the grammer or dictionary it recognizes it using one of the word in the grammer which is wrong.
For Ex:
I speak 'sendto workflow' which is not present in the grammer or dictionary it still recognizes it as 'sendto organization'. How can I solve this problem? Please help....

Comment: What exactly do you want to solve?

Comment: the words which are not present in my dictionary or grammer should get filtered; it should not replace them with other dictionary words

Comment: You need to do it yourself, because given a fixed grammar it will always try to recognize anything.

Comment: Do you know how yo do it?

Comment: It's not easy. Search for "utterance verification" or "confidence measure".